# Local nuget server: 405 Method not allowed

Tags: iis-7, nuget, nuget-server

I've configured a local nuget server as described here: http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds

I can browse to it and look at the feed. But I can not publish packages to it. I just get error 405 all the time.

I've made sure that the App Pool account has Change privileges for the Packages folder.

My config:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="requireApiKey" value="true" />
  <add key="apiKey" value="XXXXX" />
  <add key="packagesPath" value="c:\projects\nuget\Packages" />
</appSettings>
```

I've also found this issue: http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/1789. I've removed the WebDav module/handler but do still get the error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Removing webdav did work. I've just managed to remove it in the ELMAH folders and not in the root.

Correct config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
    </modules>
```

Comment: I did this in my root web.config, but no cigar. Do I have to add it somewhere else as well?

Comment: No. But make sure that the account that IIS app pool runs in have "Change" rights for the "Packages" folder (via explorer.exe)

Comment: My issue was attempting to push to `{MyNugetGallery}/api/v2/`. The correct path is `{MyNugetGallery}/api/v2/package`. I am running the master branch at commit 58d7c9. Relevant issue: http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/1793.